# (wx)Maxima: create a list of characters (as strings) without having to quote each character, individually?

Tags: string, list, character, maxima, wxmaxima

I frequently find myself needing to create a list of characters, e.g.

```
xopts:["p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z"];
```

and was looking for a way to produce these lists, without having to wrap every character in `"`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Recalled `charlist` immediately after posting.

E.g., the list in the post could be created by:

```
xopts:charlist("pqrstuvxyz");
```